# Requirement for running node on etherum

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, validators, full-node

i'm planning to run a node to do some works for learning such as snipping token, decode transaction from mempool in real-time which low latency?

I just wonder which configuration that i need to do these things. And what if i want to run on a rasberry pi, is it possiblle?

Thanks for your time